# Getting ClusterBlockException while running queries using node client

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch cluster(version 2.0) is started and the node client is built successfully, but  for some reason I'm getting the following error while running queries using node client.

```
20:15:15.479 [Pool:entitytaskscheduler: Thread#1] DEBUG c.b.o.e.t.c.DataCollectorStatusUpdateTask - collectors updated due to agent reconnected:{}
ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedRaiseException(ClusterBlocks.java:144)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:73)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:67)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:99)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:44)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
        at com.hidden.ppp.management.dc.DataCollectorPollStatusDAOESImpl.findDCIdsUpdatedInTime(DataCollectorPollStatusDAOESImpl.java:151)
        at com.hidden.ppp.engine.taskexecutor.cptaskexecs.DataCollectorStatusUpdateTask.execute(DataCollectorStatusUpdateTask.java:199)
        at com.hidden.ppp.engine.taskexecutor.cptaskexecs.DataCollectorStatusUpdateTaskRunner.run(DataCollectorStatusUpdateTaskRunner.java:27)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20:15:15.558 [Pool:entitytaskscheduler: Thread#1] WARN  c.b.o.m.d.DataCollectorPollStatusDAOESImpl - blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];
20:15:15.558 [Pool:entitytaskscheduler: Thread#1] DEBUG c.b.o.e.t.c.DataCollectorStatusUpdateTask - collectors for which polls updated after epoc time:1453128243336 - dcids: []
ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedRaiseException(ClusterBlocks.java:144)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:73)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:67)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:99)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:44)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
        at com.hidden.ppp.management.dc.DataCollectorPollStatusDAOESImpl.findDCIdsNotUpdatedInTime(DataCollectorPollStatusDAOESImpl.java:182)
        at com.hidden.ppp.engine.taskexecutor.cptaskexecs.DataCollectorStatusUpdateTask.execute(DataCollectorStatusUpdateTask.java:204)
        at com.hidden.ppp.engine.taskexecutor.cptaskexecs.DataCollectorStatusUpdateTaskRunner.run(DataCollectorStatusUpdateTaskRunner.java:27)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
```

I've even disabled the "multicast" as per this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/elasticsearch/uNRGDdwAi-g) - still no luck. Surprisingly, I could access the elasticsearch from sense. Any clues on what is going wrong ?

Comment: I'm having same problem. Still looking into it.
Have you had any success?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error message and was not able to understand the problem first. I was developing a node client Java application on my laptop, using an Elasticsearch data node on a remote server. For production use, I needed to deploy the Java application on this remote server.

I configured the Java application to talk to the local host only (being on the same host now):

```
elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=127.0.0.1
```

And got the same exception

```
ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];]
```

Looking at the logs I also found this entry:

```
[WARN] [TP-Processor2] DiscoveryService.waitForInitialState -> [cerbera] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
```

So basically, the question was: **Why doesn't it find the Elasticsearch data node?** I changed port ranges and also played with the `multicast` setting - without success.

Finally, I checked `elasticsearch.yml` and found the data node not listening to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`), but instead on the ethernet interface `192.168.1.2`.

```
network.host: 192.168.1.2
http.port: 9200
```

The final change was simple, I just needed to reconfigure the node client configuration to talk to the correct interface

```
elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=192.168.1.2
```

Now my node client is talking to elasticsearch **via the correct interface**. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (using k8s ) I finally replaced my elastic image and the issue was solved...
moved from 6.5.4-debian-9-r41 to 6.8.16-debian-10-r5 ([using bitnami images)](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/elasticsearch/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated)
I know it is not the best answer - but I really tried suggested answers and nothing worked for me. so my recommendation is to update to a newer better version. (docker makes that easy:) )